# Is it possible to know the methodology of built in functions?

Tags: javascript, function, parsefloat, built-in

I want to understand the logic behind `parseFloat()` in JS. Is it possible to dissect library functions to know how they've been written?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534192/algorithm-for-javascript-pre-defined-functions-parseint-parsefloat-isnan-etc

Comment: yes, the functions are laid out in detail in the ecmaScript spec. the actual guts are secret, but every step they must perform is published.

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation can vary a bit, but you can certainly see the source code of V8, which is open:

https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror