# Source code for Array.prototype.concat()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can I check how internally Java Script APIs are implemented. For example, I want to check how methods in Array.prototype or String.prototype are implemented.
Thanks
Datha

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15534256)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is implemented by browsers. So the implementation of different Javascript APIs will be browser specific and you will have to look at browser's source code, which might be in any language, not necessarily Javascript. Most of the commercial browsers are not open source so you wont be able to look at their source code. However chromium is open source , so if you want to have a look at their source code you can find it here [Chromium git repo](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git)